# Gradle 2.4 - Excute a Groovy-Script-file in run-task after compileGroovy-task

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I need to start a groovy script during the gradle-`run`-task after the `compileGroovy`-task, in order to create some resources. Therefore I have made the following `build.gradle`-file:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin:'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.3'
}

task myTask << {
    new GroovyShell().run(file('/src/someScript.groovy'))
}
myTask.mustRunAfter(compileGroovy)
myTask.dependsOn(compileGroovy)
```

Problem is: `myTask` is never executed when I execute the `run`-task.

How can I let `myTask` be executed after `compileGroovy`-task, which is nested inside `run`-task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
compileGroovy.finalizedBy(myTask)
```

It should solve the problem.